# Select download server based on location?

Tags: php, geolocation

I have 2 servers, One in Amsterdam and one in Kansas City. I would like to automatically select the closest server based on location so they get the fastest speed.

I've got Longitude/Latitude for both places,

Kansas = Lat = 39.099727 / Long = -94.578567 :
Amsterdam = Lat = 52.370216 / Long = 4.895168

What would be the best way to determine the closest server to the user? I need to be able to do it with PHP if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Closest does not mean the fastest. I recomend you go with ping time. Request `microtime(true)` from each server, immediately after receiving request it once again, the difference will give you approximately ping time times 3. Select the server with smaller ping time.

Comment: Only issue is the 2 download servers aren't running php. They are just used as download servers. I host my main website on a separate server. Does that rule out this method ?

Comment: You can use some way of pinging with javascript. Eg request random nonexisting web page and check how long it takes. Server's processing time will be included, but that is actually good.